# Field found by index and not by name

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic, adodb

Here is my problem, I have this query:

```
SQL = "SELECT * 
       FROM Items, Genre, Artist 
       WHERE Artist.ID = " & SelArtist & " AND 
             Items.Artist = Artist.ID AND 
             Items.Genre = Genre.ID"
```

And I need to get `Items.Song` from it.
If I go with the "index print" it all works out and print the correct field

```
Response.Write(Recordset.Fields(3).Value)
```

But if I choose to go with the field name

`Response.Write(Recordset.Fields("Items.Song"))`

then It gives me the following error:

> ADODB.Recordset error '800a0cc1'
>
> Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested
>   name or ordinal.

Which, if I'm not wrong means he can't simply find the field I'm searching for and often it is because the name is mispelled or simply the query is wrong. In my case I'm sure it's none of either cases so I really don't know what to do about it.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You can't prefix your column names, your record set is independent of your query, all it knows is that there is a column called "Song", it has no knowledge which table it came from. This is one reason why [you should not be using `SELECT *`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list). You have no control over ambiguous column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing to:

```
Response.Write(Recordset.Fields("Song"))
```